# Showing ActionSheet in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have to present a `UIActionsheet` on iPad upon tapping on a `UIBarButtonItem`. At present, I have three `UIBarButtonItem`s on the right side of the navigation bar. On tapping the rightmost `UIBarButtonItem`, the `UIActionSheet` is to be displayed. Also for the rightmost bar button item, a custom button is created and is added in the `customView` property of `UIBarButtonItem`. I am not understanding what data is to be provided for `sourceView` and `sourceRect` for displaying the action sheet in proper position:

```
 alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect
 alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView
```

Comment: You can use your `rightBarButtonItem`. Like:
`alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = rightBarButtonItem.frame`
`alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = rightBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sheet to point at the UIBarButtonItem that you activated it from, simply do this:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = <the desired BarButtonItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two *different* ways of supplying an arrow source:

- `barButtonItem`
- **Or**, `sourceView` plus `sourceRect`.

There have to be two ways, because a bar button item is not a view and has no source rect.

You want to use the *first* way. Set the `barButtonItem`. Don't set the `sourceView` or `sourceRect`.